# Difference of 2 - SIGSEGV (11) [Codewars]

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, memory-access

I've been trying to do the [following Kata on Codewars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5340298112fa30e786000688):

> The objective is to return all pairs of integers from a given array of integers that have a difference of 2.
>
> The result array should be sorted in ascending order of values.
>
> Assume there are no duplicate integers in the array. The order of the integers in the input array should not matter.

This is my solution, but its crashing with `SIGSEGV (11). Invalid memory access.`

Can someone please help?

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Integer_Pair {
    int a;
    int b;
} pair;

// N.B. assign the size of the return array to the pointer *z
size_t twos_difference(size_t n, const int array[n], size_t *z) {

    pair* tot = malloc(sizeof(pair));

    if (tot == NULL)
        return 0;

    int temp[n];

    int val;

    // Counter for tot
    int c = 0;

    // Copy array elements in temp for later comparison
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = array[i];
    }


    // Sort array and store in ascending order into temp 
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (temp[i] > temp[j])
            {
                val = temp[i];
                temp[i] = temp[j];
                temp[j] = val;
            }
        }
    }

    // If difference between 2 numbers is 2, store in tot
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (temp[i] - array[j] == -2)
            {
                tot[c].a = array[i];
                tot[c].b = temp[j];
                c++;
            }
        }
    }

    // Copy number of pairs with difference of 2 in tot
    *z = c;

    return *z;

    free(tot);

}
```

Comment: With a Segmentation Fault, the first question should always be when using arrays "Am I trying to access memory that I don't have access to?" As I can't see the declared sizes of your arrays, this would be my best advice to you.

Comment: `for(size_t j = + 1; j < n; j++)` ? I think you meant something else here

Comment: yess, i + 1, I correct it

Comment: Are the sizes of temp[] and array[] the same? What are they exactly?

Comment: ```pair* tot = malloc(sizeof(pair));``` Also, this should be casted ```pair* tot = (pair*) malloc(sizeof(pair));```

Comment: yes ,same size,(size_t n)

Comment: @NullPointer This is C. casting to/from `void*` is [neither required nor recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: regarding; `return *z; free(tot);`  the call to `free()` will never be executed because the function has already exited due to the prior call to `return`

Comment: OT: regarding: `int c = 0;`  The variable `c` is being assigned to a `size_t`.  To avoid possible errors, the statement should be: `size_t c = 0;`

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: OT: regarding: `if (tot == NULL) return 0;`  This fails to tell the user there is a problem nor what the problem is.  Suggest:  `if (tot == NULL) { perror( "malloc failed" ); return 0; }`  Which will output to `stderr` both the error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.

Comment: regarding: `for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (temp[i] - array[j] == -2)`  the array `temp[]` is already sorted, so no need to be looking at: `array[]`  Rather, just look at `temp[]`  similar to: `for (size_t i = 0; i < (n-1); i++)
    {
        if( (temp[i+1] - temp[i]) == 2 )
            z[i].a = temp[i];
            z[i].b = temp[i+1];
        }
    }`

Comment: also, for robustness, initialize the `z[]` to all -1 before checking for 'difference by 2'   Then the caller will be able to easily determine when all the 'valid' pairs have been examined.

Comment: given the posted code, each pair will be 'counted' twice.  This could (if lots of pairs with difference of 2) overrun an array of `n` values in the `array[]` which would also result in undefined behavior and could result in a seg fault event

Answer (score 4):

> pair* tot = malloc(sizeof(pair));

Here, you are allocating only one instance of `pair`.

> tot[c].a = array[i];
> tot[c].b = temp[j];

Here, you are accessing more than one instance of `pair`

You need allocate more elements. `pair* tot = malloc(n*sizeof(pair));`

Comment: @DM880 without a proper [mcve] that's probably the best you're gonna get here. That said, the code you posted has zero reason for using `tot` in the first place. It is allocated, data stored in it, but never referenced thereafter anywhere, and due to the premature return statement, ultimately leaked.

Comment: @DM880 In the question, you are supposed to return the pairs , not the  number of pairs. Please check the question.

Comment: @WhozCraig sorry for that ,I'm new to this,I'll try to follow the proper minimal reproducible example next time

Answer (score -1):

`pair* tot = malloc(sizeof(pair));` 
should be changed to 
`pair* tot = (pair *)malloc(sizeof(pair));`
and your return statement 
`if (tot == NULL)`
should have the statement on the same line or indented: 
`if (tot == NULL) return 0;` 
The first change will fix your SIGSEGV exception, the second is just good coding practice and makes your code more readable.

Comment: There is no need to cast the result of malloc. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc#:~:text=If%20you%20use%20malloc%20in,will%20return%20a%20void*%20type.

Comment: I've tried but nothing changed,thanks for the advice

Comment: The first change will have no effect whatever on the compiled code and so will certainly not fix the segfault.  Nor will the second, of course.